# You seem you haven't voted after redirecting to another page and coming back

Tags: support, voting

Vote a question or answer. Then click on a link to redirect to another [page](http://google.com). Use the Back button of your browser. When you come back, it seems you never voted. You need to refresh the page to see your vote.

Comment: That's due to the back functionality of the browser, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can't be handled somehow?

Comment: I mean, it's possible, but it would be an undertaking to implement, when you could simply realize that the back button is going to show you the page as it would when you first loaded that page, not the most recent state of the page.

Comment: Sure, that's way it works. But, confusing sometimes. You might revote

Comment: but as you can only vote once, there's no impact.

Comment: Hey @Jude, don't take it bad. Take a sad question score, and make it better. Remember to let us into your heart. Then you can start to make it better.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier *applause*

Comment: You can either update the DOM dynamically, or *every action on a page must post back to the server*. So be happy!  You've traded an instantaneous vote and other actions that don't require you reload the current webpage for seeing an older version of a page when you hit the back button. You end up saving hours a week waiting for SO (and almost every other webpage on the web nowadays) to post your input back to the web server and days waiting for the reply and for the browser to re-render the page.  Be happy, damn your eyes!

Answer (score 12):

I believe nothing really should be done in the site to counteract the effect of navigating back in the browser. What you experience is simply what seem to be a default behaviour across browsers: when going back to a visited page, browser shows it as it was moments before.

As for your concerns, as [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356219/you-seem-you-havent-voted-after-redirecting-to-another-page-and-coming-back#comment511645_356219):

> but as you can only vote once, there's no impact.

Even if you click on the arrow a second time, the system won't let anyone actually register a second vote. All in all, I don't think that is a serious problem, if a problem it is at all.